# Handle RadioButton events after button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jradiobutton, buttongroup

help,
my questions are:

1. why isn't `itemStateChanges` triggered, I tried to put it in the inner class `ButtonHandler` and also in `RadioButtonHandler` Im having trouble with it, what is the right way to do it? 
   I want to trigger and check the marked JRadioButtons after the user click the "check" button.
2. What is the right way to check which button was clicked, I feel like comparing the strings is bad programming practise. Maybe using an ID ?
3. How should I make a "reset" button(start over), I want to uncheck all radio buttons and run the constructor once again.

Thank you for your help !

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;
    public class ExamFrame extends JFrame {

        static ArrayList<Question> qArrList;
        JRadioButton a1,a2,a3,a4;
        public ExamFrame() {
            super("Quiz");

            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            Exam exam = new Exam();
            qArrList = exam.getExam();
            int count=0;
            for(Question q : qArrList){
                count++;
                JLabel questionLabel = new JLabel(count+". "+q.getQustion()); //swing constant ?
                ArrayList<String> ansRand = q.getAllRandomAns();
                a1 = new JRadioButton(ansRand.get(0)); 
                a2 = new JRadioButton(ansRand.get(1));
                a3 = new JRadioButton(ansRand.get(2));
                a4 = new JRadioButton(ansRand.get(3));
                add(questionLabel);
                add(a1);add(a2,gbc);add(a3);add(a4);

                ButtonGroup radioGroup = new ButtonGroup(); //logical relationship
                radioGroup.add(a1);radioGroup.add(a2);radioGroup.add(a3);radioGroup.add(a4);
            }
            //buttons:
            JButton checkMe = new JButton("Check Exam");
            JButton refresh = new JButton("Start Over");
            ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
            checkMe.addActionListener(handler);
            refresh.addActionListener(handler);
            add(checkMe);
            add(refresh);

        }
            /** Listens to the radio buttons. */
            public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Start Over")){ //id?
                        //how to do this?

                    }
                    else{
                        RadioButtonHandler handler = new RadioButtonHandler();
                        a1.addItemListener(handler);
                        System.out.println("success?");
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ExamFrame.this, String.format("You pressed: %s", e.getActionCommand()));
                }
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) //can i add it here?
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ExamFrame.this, String.format("yes?"));
                    System.out.println("success!");
                }

            }
            public class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener
            {
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ExamFrame.this, String.format("radio state changed"));

                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: For the refresh button per example, you can do `if(e.getSource() == refresh)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why "itemStateChanges" isn't triggered, i tried to put it in the inner
>   class "ButtonHandler" and also in "RadioButtonHandler" Im having
>   troubles with it, what is the right way to do it? I want to trigger
>   and check the marked JRadioButtons after the user click the "check"
>   button.

`ButtonHandler` is implemented with `ActionListener` only:

```
  public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{}
```

The `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent)` function belongs to `ItemListener`. This function is triggered if state of a source component to which this listener is registered gets changed. So implement the `ItemListener`. However, one more thing to note, that `JButton` doesn't respond to `ItemListener` but `JRadioButton` will. Because this `Item` events are fired by components that implement the `ItemSelectable` interface. Some example of such components are:  *check boxes, check menu items, toggle buttons and combo boxes including Radio Buttons* as mentioned above.

---

> What is the right way to check which button was clicked, i feel like
>   comparing the strings is wrong programming. Maybe using an ID

Well using the event source function: `e.getSource()`, check whither the type of the source is your expected type and cast it to appropriate type. And then you can use `getName(String)` function and check the name you were expecting. Of-course you should assign the name using `setName(String)` after initialization of component. Or using the component reference directly if it is declared in the Class context and you have direct access to the component.

```
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            if(e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox)
            { 
                JCheckBox  checkBox = (JCheckBox)e.getSource();
                if(checkBox.getName().equals("expectedName"))
                          ; // do my thing
             }
        }
```

---

> How should i make a "reset" button(start over), i want to uncheck all
>   radio buttons and run the constructor once again.

Well you are working with `ButtonGroup`. And `ButtonGroup` has a nice function: [`clearSelection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#clearSelection%28%29) to help with whatever(*I could not understand the part: run the constructor part*) you want.

**Edit: As you wanted me to see an `ItemListener` implemented class, Yes i can see that But:**

1. i can not see that you have actually registered an instance of that class(`a1.addItemListener(handler);`) to any component before performing any action on the component to which `ButtonHandler` is registered to: `checkMe, refresh`
2. In addition to that, in this action performed function, you are checking with
   action command, which you haven't even set with `JButton.setActionCommand(String)` function. *You should not assign a (Item)listener depending on event-occurrence of another (Action)listener.*

**Tutorial:**

1. [How to Write an ItemListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html)
2. [How to Write an ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
3. [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html)

Comment: As u can see i have a class that implements ItemListener:

public class RadioButtonHandler implements ItemListener

So your answer for the first question didnt helped me

Comment: Check the edit please. And try to make your question short in future. It took me almost half an hour to write this post. You might want to argue that i might lack in skills, but as i don't see any other answer addressing your issue, it is safe to assume that everyone avoided your question for it's large scale size